# Running out of application memory on Macbook Pro 2015/Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: memory

I'm constantly running out of application memory on Macbook Pro 2015/Sierra 10.12.6. This problem happens every few minutes. I have tried restarting several times using the specific method described in an earlier post. Besides Google, I have no other applications open on my laptop, and only one tab is open at any given point. I have also moved out a lot of my video and image files, so there is plenty of space on my hard drive. I ran the activity monitor when this problem occurred. Screen shot of activity monitor is attached. Any advice will be greatly appreciated!
[image: Activity Monitor screenshot]

Comment: Can you open terminal.app and enter `df -h` then hit enter? Your system volume is usually /dev/disk1 but will definitely be the volume that is listed as Mounted On = `/`. Check how much free space df says you have. After that, enter into terminal.app `top -o mem` just in case something that is using a lot of memory isn't appearing in Activity Monitor. How much RAM is your system configured with?

Comment: Chrome is notorious for gobbling up memory. Since it's the only application running, then it's a fairly obvious culprit. Do you get the same problem with any other single app running? Any reason you're still on Sierra? Maybe update your OS and get the latest version of Chrome. Or use another browser.

Comment: @Scottmeup. Appreciate your help. I followed your instructions and got the following after I entered df_h



Filesystem      /dev/disk1 

Size    465Gi 

Used   67Gi 

Avail   397Gi 

Capacity 15%

iused      753640

ifree 4294213639

% iused  0%

Mounted on/

Comment: That's good, it looks like there's plenty of storage on that drive. Did `top -o mem` then enter from terminal.app show anything using a lot of memory that wasn't showing up in activity monitor? How much memory is your system configured with? You can view this by clicking the apple logo in the top left on the menu bar and selecting "About This Mac".